# Displaying innerHTML of the elements in IE in the immediate window

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am navigating to a web page in IE using VBA. The elements of the web page loads dynamically after a few seconds.
I am trying to work with a tree structure with links in that web page. So I was trying to view the inner HTML using the following code,

```
    Sub treemenutest()

    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim elements3 As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim nameValueInput3 As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
    Dim LIS As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim LI As IHTMLElement

    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate Sheet1.TextBox1.Value 'web page URL

    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set doc = ie.document

    Set elements3 = doc.getElementsByName("OK")
    If Not elements3 Is Nothing Then
        Set nameValueInput3 = elements3(1)
           If Not nameValueInput3 Is Nothing And nameValueInput3.Type = "submit" Then _
                   nameValueInput3.Click
           End If

    Set LIS = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For i = 0 To LIS.Length - 1
    Debug.Print LI.innerHTML
    Next

    End Sub
```

Debug.Print is not displaying any info in the immediate window. Is there something wrong with the coding or is it because the some contents of the webpage are dynamic?

Any info will be helpful.

Comment: Is it possible for you to reveal the link of that webpage to get a quicker solution?

Comment: It's an official site so I cannot reveal it.

Comment: You will find it easier to use your browser's Developer Tools (press F12 to open) - that will show you the current HTML just by clicking on the element of interest.

Comment: @Tim Williams actually when I am pressing F12 on an element, I could see the elements with tag "a". But I couldn't access those using my VBA. So I wanted to figure out the index of those elements.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a foreach loop

```
For each LI in LIS
    Debug.Print LI.innerHTML 
Next
```

But you can also iterate over the tags like this:

```
For i = 0 To LIS.Length - 1
    Debug.Print LIS.item(i).innerHTML
Next
```

Comment: I have tried using the for each loop..but still my immediate window turns out empty.

Comment: I would type `Stop` before the loop and then execute the code.  From there I would work the code out directly from the Immediate Window.  As you set the variables check the Locals Window and look through the variable properties until you get it to work.

Comment: Since you are clicking a Submit button, you should probably wait for the new document to load  ` Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4 :        DoEvents :    Loop`.

Comment: I have added the Do Until..Loop. I also tried adding LIS.Length  and LIS.item(i).innerHTML to the watch window, but the value is only displayed as <out of context>.

Comment: The immediate window also turns out empty.